# Running QGIS plugin developed for old version in newer version?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

My company developed a non-public plugin to QGIS 2.6 in 2013. Now we have to run this plugin again.

Is it possible to make it run in QGIS 2.18?

Comment: I don't think much has changed in terms of the [API](http://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) so I should guess your plugin could still work (also difficult to say as we don't know what your plugin does). One thing you may have to change is `pluginqgisMinimumVersion=2.18` in your plugin _metadata.txt_ file so that QGIS 2.18 won't complain.